# Visual Studio 2022 JIT not kicking in

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, jit

1. I launch a native C++ console project in VS.
2. I detach the debugger.
3. the app crashes
4. JIT mechanism does not kick-in. nothing.

verified on Windows 11 / Windows Server 2022

- Triple checked native JIT debugging is enabled in VS.
- Tried to play around with registry settings as well.
- VS running as Admin

We are facing this very issue on fresh installs of Windows Server 2022, and latest version of Visual Studio 2022 all updates installed. Seems like sort of a basic functionality to have. We are running 7+ servers simultaneously and each of these is facing this issue.

Ideas?

Comment: Add the [DontShowUI registry key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings), set it to 0.

Comment: @HansPassant did not help unfortunately sort of a basic thing to require it seems but we are facing this very issue over 7+ servers latest version of Visual Studio 2022 and Windows Server 2022.....

having debugger attached imposes too much overhead in out multi-threaded app.. thus JIT is required.

Comment: Hmm, worked just fine when I tested it on Win11, 22H2.  It enables the WER crash dialog, which popped up when I intentionally crashed a test program.  It briefly tried to contact Microsoft's server, then displayed the Debug button.  Clicking it presented the JIT debugger selection screen, selecting VS gave me a debug break on the line that crashed the program.  Just like it did on Win7.  I added DontShowUI to the HKCU registry key.  Do verify that these crashes right now produce an entry in the Windows application event log.

Comment: DontShowUI as a DWORD 64-bit value set to 0, correct?

Comment: A 32-bit value.

Comment: ok, enabled  DontShowUI - as  32 bit value set to 0 on all servers, fingers crosses, let's see

Comment: that did not change anything.. to reproduce create any C++ console project, launch debugger, DETACH.... JIT wouldn't start when it crashes. App returns some error code the console window stays with it displayed, nothing more.

Comment: Well this FIXED the issue.

I have no idea whether it took some time for Windows to refresh setting from the registry (no reboot was needed though) but the DontSHowUI flag did the trick (when set as a 32 bit value). Thank you! If you create an 'answer' I would 'accept' @Hans

Comment: @HansPassant thank you so much,, it worked , waiting for an 'official' answer so that I could accept.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was almost certain there used to be a mechanism which would auto-recognize full username based in first characters used if a matching username was in a  thread, seems I was wrong, thanks,